# Get a random item from list using kotlin streams

Tags: random, kotlin

How to get a random item from a list in an easy and concise way.
ex: if I want to get an even random number from this list that.

```
val list = listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9).filter { it % 2 == 0 }
```

Note:
I know there are some similar answers in java that solves this problem but I think we can have a more concise way in kotlin.

Answer (score 65):

### Kotlin 1.3 and above:

**Kotlin 1.3 is now available with Multiplatform Random Number Generator!**
You can use it like this :

```
import kotlin.random.Random

fun main() {
    println(Random.nextBoolean())
    println(Random.nextInt())
}
```

[Try it online!](https://pl.kotl.in/BJViWYa27)

or in your case

```
fun main() {
    val list = (1..9).filter { it % 2 == 0 }
    println(list.random())
}
```

[Try it online!](https://pl.kotl.in/rJJomKanm)

---

### Kotlin 1.2

Since Kotlin 1.2, we have [`Iterable.shuffled()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/shuffled.html). This method could help you with the use of [`List.take()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/take.html) to extract the number of element you want (only one in this example).

```
val list = (1..9).filter { it % 2 == 0 }
return list.shuffled().take(1)[0]
```

This method is less optimized than before 1.2 one but it work on multiplatform context. Use the one you need according to your context.

---

### Before Kotlin 1.2

Before Kotlin 1.2, no solution exists on a Multiplatform context to generate Random Number. The most easy solution is to call the Platform Random directly.

#### JVM

On the JVM we use `Random` or even `ThreadLocalRandom` if we're on JDK > 1.6.

```
import java.util.Random

fun IntRange.random() = Random().nextInt((endInclusive + 1) - start) + start
```

#### JS

On the JS, we use `Math.Random`.

```
fun IntRange.random() = (Math.random() * ((endInclusive + 1) - start) + start).toInt()
```

Comment: I was using this method but I need to shuffle the whole list which is externally inefficient. when all you want is to get a random element.

Comment: the implementation of shuffled iterate over all the list items.  
and how this is more more flexible and work on multi-platform context.

Comment: java.util.Random is not available on Kotlin-js or Kotlin-native. If you doesn't want to re-implement your own random number generator, it's the only possible method.

If you need to pick 3 values randomly from your list, shuffled().take() can do it, not your method (but it's not your use case).

Comment: why not "list.shuffled()[0]"

Comment: Because with take you can extract 1 or more value. If you need only one value your solution is pretty the same.

Answer (score 31):

I think the easiest and the most concise way is to create extension function that returns a random element so it can be used this way:

```
val random = list.random()
```

the extension function:

```
/**
 * Returns a random element.
 */
fun <E> List<E>.random(): E? = if (size > 0) get(Random().nextInt(size)) else null
```

thanks to @Francesco comment here is another function that takes a Random instance as the source of randomness

```
/**
 * Returns a random element using the specified [random] instance as the source of randomness.
 */
fun <E> List<E>.random(random: java.util.Random): E? = if (size > 0) get(random.nextInt(size)) else null
```

Comment: Beware of using a newly-initialized `Random` instance each time. Usually randomness takes a few calls to adjust to an acceptable threshold.

Comment: interesting, I can think of a variant of this method that takes prespecified Random. I will add it. thanks for the note.

Comment: Current implementation of `Random()` is: 
`public Random() { this(seedUniquifier() ^ System.nanoTime());}`

@FrancescoMenzani , what is your concern regarding newly-initialized instances?

Comment: My concern would be more about object creation on every call. Also, I'd suggest making the one stored instance private so that it's only accessible in the file where it's declared.

Answer (score 20):

Shuffling the whole list just to get a single random number is a waste of performance.

Use [`random()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/random.html) instead which was introduced in Kotin 1.3

```
val randomNumber = listOf(1, 6, 8).random()
```

---

For your special use-case it would make sense to first filter the list and choose a random number from the remaining items.

```
val list = listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9)
val randomEvenNumber = list.filter { it % 2 == 0 }.random()
```

Comment: What will be the possible outputs for 2nd solution? Plz mention.

Comment: @AhamadullahSaikat Possible outpus: 2, 4, 6 (all even numbers)

Comment: Willi Mentzel              tnx

Answer (score 2):

As stated by others, `list.random()` should do the trick now but if you don't know if the list is empty, `.random()` could throw an exception. Short of implementing `.randomOrNull()` as an extension function you can also hack it using `list.shuffled().firstOrNull()` but beware this is slow for long lists.

The `.randomOrNull()` approach:

```
fun <E> List<E>.randomOrNull(): E? = if (size > 0) random() else null
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want 25 random elements from a list, I do it like this:

```
var suliTraffic = ArrayList<SuliTraffic>()
var randomsuliTraffic = ArrayList<SuliTraffic>()

// I have add some data to my Array List
randomsuliTraffic.add(new)

// Here i shuffle all the information i have wich is over 400 object
randomsuliTraffic.shuffle()

// now you can just simply get 25 item from this randomsuliTraffic like this
for (i in randomsuliTraffic.take(25)){
    suliTraffic.add(i)
}
```

Now you can find 25 random elements in the `suliTraffic` list.

Answer (score 0):

```
fun <E> List<E>.getRandomListElements(): List<E>? = if (isNotEmpty()) this.shuffled().take(Random.nextInt(size)) else null
```